# CONCAT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I've been researching the concat function extensively but hit a wall creating a temp table. I have two columns: ID (ex. 4323) and Source (ex. PHI). I want to add a column that includes a prefix of "API-" to the ID column (ex. API-4332). Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

All rows?

```
UPDATE TheTable
   SET id = 'API-'||id;
```

Or,

```
UPDATE TheTable
   SET id = CONCAT('API-',id);
```

EDIT:

Your problem statement led me to believe you wanted to create a new column ("I want to add a column..."). Sorry for the confusion. I have changed the answer to update the ID column.

Comment: Then used the second example and got a ORA_00904: "NEWCOL" invalid identifier.

Comment: @Poohbreezy, Try with your column name (`id`) instead of `newcol`.